# Как добраться до ангулярных данных, привязанных к элементу?

Tags: angularjs, angular2, отладка

Отлаживаю приложение на ангуляре и нужно в консоли браузера получить данные, к которым делается привязка у выбранного dom-элемента. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## AngularJS

Скоуп выбранного элемента можно получить через

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

## Angular в debug-режиме

Компонент, к которому относится данный элемент, можно получить через

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance
```

Для prod-режима способ пока не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Для Chrome плагин Augury. А можно сразу из Visual Studio Code.
Так же можно дебажить и из продуктов JetBrains(IDEA и WebStorm)
Хотя из Visual Studio Code проще всего.